# How to create .deb package from JavaFx project?

Tags: linux, javafx, installation, debian, deb

I wan't to create installer for my JavaFx application project (.deb package). I discovered that this can be done using intellij, but It's not working for my project. Deb package is created, but after installation my app is not running. Besides I wan't to customize this package. From the main debian page I read that I need to create a "control" file and with `dpkg-deb --build` I can create a package. But I don't know how to configure the "control" file and how to connect it all to the Main.java boot class or to the generated jar file. I'm looking for tips or advise how to do it best.

Comment: Create an app-image instead of a deb package (just change `--type=deb` to `--type=app-image` in the jpackage command); then run the application from the command line using the app-image. That way if there are exceptions being thrown you should see the stack trace on the command line, so you can diagnose the problem. You can also modify the app-image with the control file (I'm not familiar with `.deb` packages) and then build the `.deb` from the modified image: see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/image-and-runtime-modifications.html)

Answer (score 1):

I used intellij to create a .deb package with it, but should this package be that big? (67MB) It is around 250MB to install. My .jar file with dependencies weighs 1.9MB. I have looked at this package and there are various libraries through which this package weighs so much (mainly amd64 and ext):

```
 ── lib
│   ├── amd64
│   │   ├── jli
│   │   │   └── libjli.so
│   │   ├── jvm.cfg
│   │   ├── libattach.so
│   │   ├── libavplugin-53.so
│   │   ├── libavplugin-54.so
│   │   ├── libavplugin-55.so
│   │   ├── libavplugin-56.so
│   │   ├── libavplugin-57.so
│   │   ├── libavplugin-ffmpeg-56.so
│   │   ├── libavplugin-ffmpeg-57.so
│   │   ├── libavplugin-ffmpeg-58.so
│   │   ├── libawt_headless.so
│   │   ├── libawt.so
│   │   ├── libawt_xawt.so
│   │   ├── libbci.so
│   │   ├── libdcpr.so
│   │   ├── libdecora_sse.so
│   │   ├── libdeploy.so
│   │   ├── libdt_socket.so
│   │   ├── libfontmanager.so
│   │   ├── libfxplugins.so
│   │   ├── libglassgtk2.so
│   │   ├── libglassgtk3.so
│   │   ├── libglass.so
│   │   ├── libglib-lite.so
│   │   ├── libgstreamer-lite.so
│   │   ├── libhprof.so
│   │   ├── libinstrument.so
│   │   ├── libj2gss.so
│   │   ├── libj2pcsc.so
│   │   ├── libj2pkcs11.so
│   │   ├── libjaas_unix.so
│   │   ├── libjava_crw_demo.so
│   │   ├── libjavafx_font_freetype.so
│   │   ├── libjavafx_font_pango.so
│   │   ├── libjavafx_font.so
│   │   ├── libjavafx_iio.so
│   │   ├── libjava.so
│   │   ├── libjawt.so
│   │   ├── libjdwp.so
│   │   ├── libjfr.so
│   │   ├── libjfxmedia.so
│   │   ├── libjfxwebkit.so
│   │   ├── libjpeg.so
│   │   ├── libjsdt.so
│   │   ├── libjsig.so
│   │   ├── libjsoundalsa.so
│   │   ├── libjsound.so
│   │   ├── liblcms.so
│   │   ├── libmanagement.so
│   │   ├── libmlib_image.so
│   │   ├── libnet.so
│   │   ├── libnio.so
│   │   ├── libnpt.so
│   │   ├── libprism_common.so
│   │   ├── libprism_es2.so
│   │   ├── libprism_sw.so
│   │   ├── libresource.so
│   │   ├── libsaproc.so
│   │   ├── libsctp.so
│   │   ├── libsplashscreen.so
│   │   ├── libsunec.so
│   │   ├── libt2k.so
│   │   ├── libunpack.so
│   │   ├── libverify.so
│   │   ├── libzip.so
│   │   └── server
│   │       ├── libjsig.so
│   │       ├── libjvm.so
│   │       └── Xusage.txt
│   ├── calendars.properties
│   ├── charsets.jar
│   ├── classlist
│   ├── cmm
│   │   ├── CIEXYZ.pf
│   │   ├── GRAY.pf
│   │   ├── LINEAR_RGB.pf
│   │   ├── PYCC.pf
│   │   └── sRGB.pf
│   ├── content-types.properties
│   ├── currency.data
│   ├── deploy.jar
│   ├── ext
│   │   ├── cldrdata.jar
│   │   ├── dnsns.jar
│   │   ├── jaccess.jar
│   │   ├── jfxrt.jar
│   │   ├── localedata.jar
│   │   ├── meta-index
│   │   ├── nashorn.jar
│   │   ├── sunec.jar
│   │   ├── sunjce_provider.jar
│   │   ├── sunpkcs11.jar
│   │   └── zipfs.jar
│   ├── flavormap.properties
│   ├── fontconfig.bfc
│   ├── fontconfig.properties.src
│   ├── fontconfig.RedHat.5.bfc
│   ├── fontconfig.RedHat.5.properties.src
│   ├── fontconfig.RedHat.6.bfc
│   ├── fontconfig.RedHat.6.properties.src
│   ├── fontconfig.SuSE.10.bfc
│   ├── fontconfig.SuSE.10.properties.src
│   ├── fontconfig.SuSE.11.bfc
│   ├── fontconfig.SuSE.11.properties.src
│   ├── fontconfig.Turbo.bfc
│   ├── fontconfig.Turbo.properties.src
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── fonts.dir
│   │   ├── LucidaBrightDemiBold.ttf
│   │   ├── LucidaBrightDemiItalic.ttf
│   │   ├── LucidaBrightItalic.ttf
│   │   ├── LucidaBrightRegular.ttf
│   │   ├── LucidaSansDemiBold.ttf
│   │   ├── LucidaSansRegular.ttf
│   │   ├── LucidaTypewriterBold.ttf
│   │   └── LucidaTypewriterRegular.ttf
│   ├── hijrah-config-umalqura.properties
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── cursors
│   │   │   ├── cursors.properties
│   │   │   ├── invalid32x32.gif
│   │   │   ├── motif_CopyDrop32x32.gif
│   │   │   ├── motif_CopyNoDrop32x32.gif
│   │   │   ├── motif_LinkDrop32x32.gif
│   │   │   ├── motif_LinkNoDrop32x32.gif
│   │   │   ├── motif_MoveDrop32x32.gif
│   │   │   └── motif_MoveNoDrop32x32.gif
│   │   └── icons
│   │       ├── sun-java_HighContrastInverse.png
│   │       ├── sun-java_HighContrast.png
│   │       ├── sun-java_LowContrast.png
│   │       └── sun-java.png
│   ├── javafx.properties
│   ├── javaws.jar
│   ├── jce.jar
│   ├── jexec
│   ├── jfr
│   │   ├── default.jfc
│   │   └── profile.jfc
│   ├── jfr.jar
│   ├── jfxswt.jar
│   ├── jsse.jar
│   ├── jvm.hprof.txt
│   ├── locale
│   │   ├── de
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── sunw_java_plugin.mo
│   │   ├── es
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── sunw_java_plugin.mo
│   │   ├── fr
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── sunw_java_plugin.mo
│   │   ├── it
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── sunw_java_plugin.mo
│   │   ├── ja
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── sunw_java_plugin.mo
│   │   ├── ko
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── sunw_java_plugin.mo
│   │   ├── ko.UTF-8
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── sunw_java_plugin.mo
│   │   ├── pt_BR
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── sunw_java_plugin.mo
│   │   ├── sv
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── sunw_java_plugin.mo
│   │   ├── zh
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── sunw_java_plugin.mo
│   │   ├── zh.GBK
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── sunw_java_plugin.mo
│   │   ├── zh_HK.BIG5HK
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── sunw_java_plugin.mo
│   │   ├── zh_TW
│   │   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       └── sunw_java_plugin.mo
│   │   └── zh_TW.BIG5
│   │       └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │           └── sunw_java_plugin.mo
│   ├── logging.properties
│   ├── management
│   │   ├── jmxremote.access
│   │   ├── jmxremote.password.template
│   │   ├── management.properties
│   │   └── snmp.acl.template
│   ├── management-agent.jar
│   ├── meta-index
│   ├── net.properties
│   ├── oblique-fonts
│   │   ├── fonts.dir
│   │   ├── LucidaSansDemiOblique.ttf
│   │   ├── LucidaSansOblique.ttf
│   │   ├── LucidaTypewriterBoldOblique.ttf
│   │   └── LucidaTypewriterOblique.ttf
│   ├── plugin.jar
│   ├── psfontj2d.properties
│   ├── psfont.properties.ja
│   ├── resources.jar
│   ├── rt.jar
│   ├── security
│   │   ├── blacklist
│   │   ├── blacklisted.certs
│   │   ├── cacerts
│   │   ├── java.policy
│   │   ├── java.security
│   │   ├── javaws.policy
│   │   ├── policy
│   │   │   ├── limited
│   │   │   │   ├── local_policy.jar
│   │   │   │   └── US_export_policy.jar
│   │   │   └── unlimited
│   │   │       ├── local_policy.jar
│   │   │       └── US_export_policy.jar
│   │   └── trusted.libraries
│   ├── sound.properties
│   └── tzdb.dat
```

these libraries are necessary, can I somehow reduce the size of this file?